Python code for counting the number of Yahoo emails maxes out at 10,000 emails, how to fix?
I have code that uses Python to programmatically count the number of emails in each of the mailboxes of my Yahoo email account. The issue is that it maxes out at 10,000 even though some of my inboxes have over 80,000 emails. Would anyone have any ideas how this can be fixed? My code is as follows. Thanks!
import os
import getpass
import imaplib
import logging

IMAP_SERVER = 'imap.mail.yahoo.com'
MAILBOX_BLACKLIST = ['trash']

def get_credentials():
    username = input('Yahoo Mail username: ').strip()
    psswd = getpass.getpass(prompt='Yahoo Mail app-specific password: ')
    return username, psswd

def login(username, psswd):
    imap_client = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(IMAP_SERVER)
    try:
        login_status, _ = imap_client.login(username, psswd)
        if login_status == "OK":
            logging.info("Login successful")
            return imap_client
    except imaplib.IMAP4.error as e:
        logging.error(f"Login failed: {e}")
    return None

def count_emails(imap_client):
    # Get list of all mailboxes
    list_status, mailboxes = imap_client.list()
    if list_status != "OK":
        logging.error("Could not retrieve mailboxes")
        return 1
    # Filter and prepare mailbox names
    mailbox_names = [get_mailbox_name(mailbox) for mailbox in mailboxes if get_mailbox_name(mailbox).lower() not in MAILBOX_BLACKLIST]
    for mailbox_name in mailbox_names:
        try:
            open_status, _ = imap_client.select(f'"{mailbox_name}"', readonly=True)
            if open_status == "OK":
                search_status, message_set = imap_client.search(None, 'ALL')
                if search_status == "OK":
                    message_nums = message_set[0].split()
                    total_messages = len(message_nums)
                    print(f"Mailbox '{mailbox_name}' has {total_messages} emails.")
                else:
                    print(f"Search failed for mailbox {mailbox_name}")
            else:
                print(f"Could not open mailbox {mailbox_name}")
        except imaplib.IMAP4.error as e:
            print(f"Error accessing {mailbox_name}: {e}")

def get_mailbox_name(mailbox):
    mailbox = mailbox.decode('utf-8')
    mailbox_name = mailbox.split(' "/"')[-1].replace('"', '').strip()
    return mailbox_name

if __name__ == '__main__':
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
    username, psswd = get_credentials()
    imap_client = login(username, psswd)
    if not imap_client:
        logging.error("Exiting due to login failure")
        sys.exit(1)
    count_emails(imap_client)
    try:
        imap_client.logout()
    except imaplib.IMAP4.error as e:
        logging.error(f"Error during logout: {e}")
    sys.exit(0)


Yahoo mail has a limit on only accessing 10,000 mails via IMAP:

Reddit discussion
Discussion on Microsoft forums
Discussion on Apple community

The Microsoft thread in particular is pretty long and has a lot of information. Some users were able to successfully use Yahoo's "export" IMAP server to access more than the 10,000 message limit, though this may be limited to 100,000 instead.

Wonderful thanks! I changed the server to imap.mail.yahoo.com and it works now.
